# How do I access the solutions in the PlatformConfiguration?

Tags: .net, msbuild

I am currently writing a build script to deploy my windows application (see http://www.henrycordes.nl/post/2010/12/15/Deploying-a-WindowsService-using-TeamBuild-2010.aspx) that contains 2 projects.
This contains a ForEach loop iterating through all of the PlatformConfigurations.
However this loop is empty. How do I set this up?
I am sure it is very simple, but I am not clear from my Google searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I need to edit the Build Definition, select Process, expand Items to Build and enter the configuration in the Configurations to Build property.